# Can I create my own npm package script that targets a file of my NEXT.js project?

Tags: babeljs, next.js

For quicker development, I am interested in exposing one of the files of my NEXT.js project as an npm package script. This enables consuming that code in a simple way from the terminal, orchestrate maintenance tasks, etc.

Let's assume the file:

```
import { Something } from 'some_library';

console.log("Some task to be performed");
```

And in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    ...
    "mine": "execute my file" < HERE
},
```

My first intuition would be calling node directly over my file in the `mine` task, but this would fail with the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I understand the babel transpilation needs to be performed before calling my file, activity that I assume is performed automatically by the `dev` command.

Is there any way in which I could have my own task that targets code that could be used directly in NEXT.js?. Is there any way to trigger the transpilation and after execute my file?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package is not part of Next.js project and won't be transpilled by Next.js.

You can create a command (npm scripts) that calls Babel to transpile the package and then executes it but it's just confusing. Next.js projects don't include Babel as a root dependency by default, so your package would rely on a module that doesn't explicitly included.

Instead, make the package ready to use in production. Install Babel or another compiler as a dev tool in the package project. Before publishing the package, transpile it to a file that Node.js can execute.

In another words distribute executable files (the package itself) and not just a source of code of the package.